# Navigation Drawer Not working on activity with tabview

Tags: android

In my android project i have created navigation drawer as a base class.
Other activities extends that base class.Still it working fine.
But now i want to use tabs in one of my activity.For that i have used TabHost.
When i start this activity my app crashes with

```
07-20 14:48:52.891    2161-2161/com.lems.tcloud E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lems.tcloud, PID: 2161
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:831)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$
```

XML file for navigation drawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

code for navigation drawer

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected void onCreateDrawer(final int layoutResID) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

        content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, content, true);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        menuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity)
                this,                  
                mDrawerLayout,         
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  
                0,
                0
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list, menuTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }
}
```

Code for TabActivty

```
public class FavTabActivity extends NavigationDrawer {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onCreateDrawer(R.layout.activity_fav_tab);

        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(FavTabActivity.this, false);
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent(this,HotList.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("HOTLIST").setIndicator("HOTLIST").
                setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("SETTINGS").setIndicator("SETTINGS").
                setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


    }

}
```

Xml File for TAbActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:background="#FF0000">
        </TabWidget>


    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Is there are any different ways to use tabview with navigation drawer?
In my case i want navigation drawer on each activity.Also i cant use fragments because there is lots of stuff to do in my activities.

Answer (score 0):

Inflated in the **getView()** method is, in this case, the layout for the individual rows of the **ListView**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="800px"
```

Eclipse right click your ***project > select android tools > add support library.***

Comment: I am not using any  custom adapter for list view.Also if i set width and height as u said then my layout get disturbed.

Comment: if you see into logs you are facing measuring issue.Is support library not working for you.

Comment: for other activities it works fine.I am using android studio.

Comment: I am not getting you. it's does not related to studio or eclipse.for studio you need to add this into your gradle script if you require.

Comment: I have already added compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' into my gradle.